# Loading methods of a specific class from a C++ library using JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a C++ library xyz. It has many classes like `xyzA`, `xyzB` etc. I want to use the method `getAge()` from the class `xyzA` which is in the xyz library.

The `xyz.so` file already exists.

Steps I have followed:

1. Created a Java class `xyz.java`

   ```
   class xyz {

       public native int getAge();

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new xyz().getAge();
       }
       static {
           System.loadLibrary("xyz");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Created the header for the Java class.

   ```
   /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
   #include <jni.h>
   /* Header for class xyz */

   #ifndef _Included_xyz
   #define _Included_xyz
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif
   /*
    * Class:     xyz
    * Method:    getAge
    * Signature: ()I
    */
   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_xyz_getAge
     (JNIEnv *, jobject);

   #ifdef __cplusplus
   }
   #endif
   #endif
   ```
3. The cpp wrapper class looks like:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "xyz.h"
   #include <jni.h>

   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_xyz_getAge(JNIEnv *, jobject)
   {
       // some code
   }
   ```
4. I successfully compile the class as follows:

   ```
   gcc -fPIC -shared -l stdc++ -I/grid/0/gs/java/jdk64/current/include -I/grid/0/gs/java/jdk64/current/include/linux xyz.cpp
   ```
5. Then run the Java prog as:

   ```
   java -Djava.library.path=/grid/0/tmp/direct/lib xyz
   ```

   I get the following error:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: xyz.getAge()I
           at xyz.getAge(Native Method)
           at xyz.main(xyz.java:6)
   ```

It cannot find the method `getAge()` specific to the class `xyzA`. How can that method be accessed? Also, is the library getting linked through my wrapper class?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on Unix, the shared library has to be named `libxyz.so`, not `xyz.so`.

Comment: The other alternative is to use `System.load(String)`, and supply a full path and filename. However, obeying the platform convention for shared library naming is still a good idea.

Comment: `strace` can be handy to find out what the jvm is trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

Exported function names in C++ libraries are *mangled*: The plain function name is decorated with class and namespace names, parameter and return types. For instance, here is one of the methods from a boost library:

```
        ?estimate_max_state_count@?$perl_matcher@PB_WV?$alloca
tor@U?$sub_match@PB_W@boost@@@std@@U?$regex_traits@_WV?$w32_regex_traits@_W@boos
t@@@boost@@@re_detail@boost@@AAEXPAUrandom_access_iterator_tag@std@@@Z
```

The format of the name is not standardised and varies from compiler to compiler. The end result is that it is difficult to call an exported C++ member function unless you're writing another module in C++ and compiling it using the same compiler. Trying to call from Java is more trouble than it is worth.

Instead, if the C++ library is yours, export helper functions using the `extern "C"` calling convention:

```
Foo * foo;

extern "C"
{
  void myfunc()
  {
    foo->bar(); // Call C++ function within a C-style function.
  }
}
```

If the library is third-party, you should wrap it with your own library which exposes necessary functions using the C-style export, as per above.

Comment: Look at the header file: the `extern "C"` stuff is already there.

Answer (score 0):

This error normally means that the library has been successfully loaded,
but that there is an inconsistency in the signature of the function.
Globally, your code looks correct, but we do put an `extern "C"` in
front of `JNIEXPORT` in our code base.  We don't use the generated
headers, so the definition of the function is the only place we could
specify `extern "C"`.  In your case, I think that the compiler is
supposed to recognize that the function declared in the header and the
one defined in your `.cpp` are the same, and define the function as
`extern "C"`, but having never done it this way, I'm not 100% sure.  You
can verify by doing something like:

```
nm -C libxyz.so | egrep getAge
```

The function should appear as a C function, with a T in the second 
column; without the -C, it should appear unmangled.  Note that the
slightest difference in the definition and the declaration will mean
that you're defining a different function; I don't see one in the code
you've posted, but it's worth double checking.

(I'd also wrap the call to LoadLibrary in a try block, just to be sure.)

EDITED to add some additional information:

I'm not sure when and how Linux links the additional libraries needed;
we've always loaded all of our libraries explicitly.  You might try
adding a call to `dlopen` in either `JNI_OnLoad` or the constructor of a
static object.  (I would recommend this anyway, in order to control the
arguments to `dlopen`.  We found that when loading several different
`.so`, RTTI didn't work accross library boundaries if we didn't.)  I
would expect not doing so to result in a loader error, but it all
depends on when Linux tries to load `libxyz.so`; if it only does so when
the JVM calls `dlsym`, then you'll get the above error.  (I think this
depends on the arguments the JVM passes to `dlopen` when you call
`java.lang.System.LoadLibrary`: if it passes `RTLD_LAZY` or `RTLD_NOW`.
By forcing the load in `JNI_OnLoad` or the constructor of a static
object, you more or less guarantee that loader errors appear as loader
errors, and not link errors, later.)